# Hibernate and using @GeneratedValue with CockroachDB results in SQLGrammarException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, kotlin, cockroachdb

The following minimal example using a generated id with Spring Boot, Hibernate, JpaRepository, CockroachDB and Kotlin produces an `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException`.

I also tested with PostgresSQL instead of CockroachDB and this is fine.

```
|------------------------------------------------|
|                 |  PostgresSQL  |  CockroachDB |
|-----------------+---------------+--------------|
| no generated id |  OK           |  OK          |
| generated id    |  OK           |  ERROR       |
|------------------------------------------------|
```

This is the code to reproduce the issue.

---

`./src/main/kotlin/ThingService.kt`:

```
package things

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Table
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore

interface ThingRepository : JpaRepository<Thing, Long> {
}

@RestController
class ThingController(private val repository: ThingRepository) {
    @PutMapping("/thing/")
    fun save(@RequestBody t:Thing): Thing
            = repository.save(t)
}

@Entity
data class Thing (
    @Column(name="value")
    var value: String,
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    @JsonIgnore
    var id: Long = -1
)

@SpringBootApplication
class Application {
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

---

`./src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
server.port=8082

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:26257/things_db?sslmode=disable
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

---

`./build.gradle.kts`:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.2.20"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.0.0.RELEASE"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version kotlinVersion
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.4.RELEASE"
}

version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
    }
}

val test by tasks.getting(Test::class) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core")
    compile("org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    compile("org.json:json:20180130")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(module = "junit")
    }
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
}
```

---

What follows are the steps to reproduce the problem.

Download and initialize CockroachDB:

```
# download
wget -qO- https://binaries.cockroachdb.com/cockroach-v1.1.6.linux-amd64.tgz | tar xvz

# start
./cockroach-v1.1.6.linux-amd64/cockroach start --insecure
# leave terminal open in background

# init
./cockroach-v1.1.6.linux-amd64/cockroach sql --insecure -e "CREATE USER root WITH PASSWORD '123';"
./cockroach-v1.1.6.linux-amd64/cockroach sql --insecure -e "CREATE DATABASE things_db;"
./cockroach-v1.1.6.linux-amd64/cockroach sql --insecure -e "GRANT ALL ON DATABASE things_db TO root;"
```

Run data service:

```
gradle bootRun
```

And now try to PUT a thing into the service:

```
curl -w "\n" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT -d '{"value":"foo", "id":123}' http://localhost:8082/thing/
```

The response is:

```
{"timestamp":"2018-03-19T13:05:12.856+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet","path":"/thing/"}
```

However when using PostgreSQL instread of CockroachDB the result is fine

```
{"value":"foo","id":123}
```

Any idea what causes the problem or how it can be avoided when using CockroachDB?

Here are the full logs:

- CockroachDB: https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/4e64eea5457e6eea5bd627ed3c5b780c
- Spring: https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/27615d2b0308724e1202f1a2a8e2eafb

Comment: The error is not a sql error but something in-between. Could you add details about the actual query run and the sql error? You can find out how to log queries in CockroachDB [here](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/sql-faqs.html#how-do-i-log-sql-queries).

Comment: @Marc: Just added the logs to my question. If they are not sufficient, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring log has the following entry:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "sequence"

Detail: source SQL: 
  create sequence hibernate_sequence start 1 increment 1
```

Sequences are not supported in CockroachDB 1.x, but they are in 2.0 which is [still in beta](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/releases/#testing-releases). The beta status does mean that it is not considered ready for production use but it might be fine if you're just playing with CockroachDB.

Sequences in CockroachDB 2.0 follow postgres syntax and behavior with the exception of `cycle` (not yet implemented). The statement used here does not use it, only `START 1 INCREMENT 1`.

You can find more details about sequences in the [CockroachDB docs](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v2.0/create-sequence.html).